# How can I put a comma between elements of an array in *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I wonder how to put a comma between elements of an array without there being a comma at the end of the line. There are similar questions but my is a bit different because I use the *ngFor directive to display text:

```
<span *ngFor="let style of styles">
    {{style}} //If I put a comma after the text, there would be a comma at the end of the line after the  
              //last element was displayed
<span>
```

What would be an approach to solve my problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `last` value from `*ngFor`:

```
<span *ngFor="let style of styles; let last = last">
  {{style}}<ng-container *ngIf="!last">,</ng-container>
<span>
```

---

Or you can use the `first` value from `*ngFor`:

```
<span *ngFor="let style of styles; let first = first">
  <ng-container *ngIf="!first">,</ng-container> {{style}}
<span>
```

Comment: Ah! I did not know that such values exist. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

the JS approach (or TS in this case) with the [join function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). this way when your in the template the string will already have commas between the words. for example:

```
const str = ['one','two','three'];
const newStr = str.join(',');
console.log(newStr);//will output: one,two,three
```

Angular approach is to use the join function inside the template. for my opinion it's the most readable option

```
<span>{{styles.join(',')}}</span>
```

Comment: Thank you for showing other possibilities to solve my problem!

Comment: you welcome. of course this method can be embedded inside the directive            <span>{{styles.join(',')}}</span>

Comment: He could use it in the template, without the loop: `{{ styles.join(',') }}`.

Comment: @connorsFan that was the idea of my last comment, have no idea why i wrote inside a directive instead of inside the template.

Comment: I would suggest to modify your answer accordingly. It will help future readers.